En que puede afectar que ponga variables con let y var?
Esta pregunta busca explorar las diferencias y los posibles impactos de utilizar let y var al declarar variables en JavaScript, especialmente en términos de ámbito y comportamiento dentro de bloques de código.

Te voy a dar mi receta: Siempre preferir usar const, si no es posible porque debo reasignar la variable, lo cambio a let. El var nunca

Variables declaradas con var tienen un comportamiento llamado elevación, causando el hoisting


console.log(msg) //hoisting
var msg = "js"
console.log(msg)



Es como si hubiera declarado la variable y no le hubiera hecho una asignación


msg;
console.log(msg)
var msg = "js"
console.log(msg)



Es un comportamiento de JavaScript; al ser sustituido por let o const no ocurrirá el hoisting, se informará un error.


console.log(msg)
let msg = "js"
console.log(msg)



Usando let no hará el hoisting al tope del contexto en el que fue insertado.
Pero dependiendo del contexto, var se considera global cuando está en el navegador, pero en Node.js es global solo en el módulo.

let, entre otros, fue disponibilizado en ECMAScript, variando según la
fuente estará descrito como; ECMAScript 6, ECMAScript 2015, ES6,
ES2015.

